# ServiceStack SwaggerUI route location

Tags: servicestack, swagger

The documentation for [ServiceStack's SwaggerUI implementation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API) states

> Default configuration expects that ServiceStack services are available under '/api' path.

but I have my api at the root. Is there a way to change where the SwaggerUI's looks?

Answer (score 3):

I found /swagger-ui/index.html includes the JavaScript code containing the api location.

```
        window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
            discoveryUrl:'../api/resources',
            apiKey:"",
            dom_id:"swagger-ui-container",
            supportHeaderParams: false,
            supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put']
        });
```

Change the discoveryUrl to be:

```
discoveryUrl:'../resources'
```

The Swagger-UI should then correctly auto-discover the available resources.